# Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, how to setup intellisense

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

I'am staring using Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Code but miss something versus what i did in past with sql server tools:

Let's say i have a table whit this name

> T_PREFIX_TABLENAME

I'am used to type part of TABLENAME and find it: simply typiyng "TABL" make intellisense working and finding corrispondent result with a like operation, with ODT this does not work and i have to type the initial part of the table name to find it, let's say "T_PREFIX_TABL" to find same results
Since all table have a long common prefix (databas is not mine so cannot change this) i have to write large part of text making intellisense quite unuseful.

I try even Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2019 with visual studio 2019 professional but in this case intellisense simple does nothing.

I try other way: drag & drop table or comlumn from server explorer to query windows but in visual studio 2019 an entire select query in created while in vs code nothing appens.

Is there a way to have intellisense smart like the sql server tools one's?

Thanks

Comment: Is this issue on visual studio or visual studio code?

Comment: both them, i described how they works

Comment: I think you should contact with the [oracle team](https://www.oracle.com/support/contact.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue with autocomplete incorrectly doing a "begins with" search, was a bug introduced in [Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.oracledevtools) version 19.3.3. It has since been fixed in 19.3.4.

Comment: don't find it for visual studio 2019: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odtvsix-vs2019-downloads.html

Comment: yes - the feature you described, autocomplete, is not available on Visual Studio. Only Visual Studio Code.